# Active li on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to apply a selected/active effect on my tabs. So when a tab is selected it should apply the active class on it and by default the first tab is the active class. I've tried with a jquery function but not seem to work:

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8thrh/82/

```js
$(function() {
    $('#nav').find('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this.hash).show().siblings().hide();
    }).filter(':first').click();
});

$('a').on('click',function(){
   $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 11px;
    background: #fff !important;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

#nav ul {

}

#nav li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.active {
     background: #000000 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#part-1">Leage of Legends</a></li>
    <li><a href="#part-2">CS:GO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#part-3">Dota2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#part-3">Hearthstone</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <div id="part-1">
        Ma première partie
    </div>
    <div id="part-2">
        Ma deuxième partie
    </div>
    <div id="part-3">
        Ma troisième partie
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't seem to work, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for two different click bindings:

```
$(function() {
   $('#nav').find('a').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this.hash).show().siblings().hide();
       $('#nav').find('a').parent().removeClass('active')
       $(this).parent().addClass('active')
   }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9c2kxz09/1/

Also the CSS is wrong; `nav li` background cannot be made `!important`, it'll override the `active` class.

I cleaned up the css: http://jsfiddle.net/9c2kxz09/4/

Comment: It needs to change the li background on link click

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Thats the basic outline for the jQuery click event. Amend as necessary but ensure you are removing and adding the class to the same element. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is that in your fiddle, you are including jQuery 1.6, a very old version.  Include 1.9.1 at least.

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
     $('li a').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
}).first().click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8thrh/87/